# Sqlite | How do I select records from two different tables using Case?

Tags: sqlite, select, case

**Edit**
I would rather explicitly state my problem I'm facing rather than assuming the approach. There could be an easiest solution to my problem.

I need to select records by joining two different table based on the result from another table. And I have to use different joins based on the result from the first table.

If a particular record is present in the first table, I have two use inner join the first table whereas if it's not present, then I have to left join.

```
bool recordPresent = select exists (select * from firstTable where access_id = 13) as access
if (recordPresent)
results = select * from secondTable s left join firstTable f on f.access_id = s.access_id where f.access_id is null order by access_id
else
results = select * from secondTable s inner join firstTable f on f.access_id = s.access_id
```

Comment: Are the Professor and Student tables related in any way?  As in... can the two tables be JOINed by a common key of sorts?  Also, in what table does your 'age' field reside?  Since this is a database and due to this being a SQL Statement being run in your database the values your are using as a 'filter' need to be somewhere in your database.  Otherwise this logic would be handled outside of the database first... and then the query would be submitted to the database.

Comment: @CodeNovice I have updated my questions with the exact problem I'm facing. Please have a look and see if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm - I don't know of a way to implement that logic within plain old SQL.  In Oracle you would use PL/SQL.  In SSMS you would use T-SQL.  I'm not sure of the equivalent programmed logic code that is available with SQLite.